# The name 'health' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am getting this error when trying to make a text based adventure game. I dont know how to proceed without fixing this so.

```
public static void nukeCutscene() {
int health = 20;
int sanity = 20;
}

public static void dwaneDeath() {
  Thread.Sleep(200);
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("A yellow-red explosion goes into your face.");
int explosionDamage;
System.Random random = new System.Random(); 
explosionDamage = random.Next(3,9);
Console.WriteLine("-"+explosionDamage+" health. ("+health+" health now)");
  }
```

Comment: both functions exist inside a class, right?! And health should also be defined on class level. `private int health` instead of inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Without wishing to sound rude or patronising, I think what you need to do is to work your way through a very basic coding tutorial first, and then move on to writing games later.

The issue you're seeing is due to a thing called *scope*.

`health` and `sanity` are only defined within the scope of the method `nukeCutScene`. They don't exist outside of that function. A different function like `dwaneDeath` simply cannot see into the local variables of another function.

One solution might be to move your variables into an enclosing scope, like this:

```cs
public class Program
{
    static int health = 20;
    static int sanity = 20;

    public static void nukeCutscene()
    {
        // this method can see the static variables health and sanity
    }

    public static void dwaneDeath() 
    {
        // and so can this one
    }
}

But seriously, start with the basics.
```